# apache beam spark runner JobService endpoint is not starting got stucked at 98% forever

Tags: apache-beam

I am using python spark runner while trying to follow this step:

`./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow`

From https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/ it got stuck at 98%:

[image]

Comment: were you able to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. When Gradle reaches the `runners:spark:job-server:runShadow` task, the job server blocks while waiting for job submissions. You should be able to submit your Python job from another terminal.